# Blender slow, what component needs upgrade

Tags: modifiers, performance

i just bought an RTX 3080 ti rendering is very fast with it.

But a lot of things are still pretty slow, like increasing the subdivision or switching the viewport shading or sometimes moving very big meshes is laggy. Especally a lot of the modifiers take long and the viewport shading switching. And things like the Ivy plugin. When the things a generated or the viewport shading is switched the rendering is very fast.

I know TaskManager is not the best an you can not see everything that is going on but in Win11 it got pretty good. It I do some of the operations that need so much time I often check the TaskManager and none of my Pc parts seems stressed too much. I have like 2 Gigs of Ram left, no cpu thread is at 100% percent and the Gpu is often doing not very much.

I was never abled to get my ram utilisation up to 100% maybe some part is reserved?

Example:
I have a Model of a high res face. With:

- 16 Mi Vertices
- 16 Mi Faces
- 33 Mi Triangles

Mi == KK == Million
To change the viewport from Solid to Rendered (Cycles,Gpu) takes about 4 Minutes.

My Components:

- 3080 ti
- AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor, 3600 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
- B450 TOMAHAWK MAX (MS-7C02)
- 16 Gigs of Ram @ 3200 Mhz; XMP activated; Dual Mode

No components get too hot!

what should i upgrade or do to get better performance?

Comment: You listed some machine components.  Perhaps you should list the vertices faces and edges count of some of your meshes.  Perhaps you can list the render time as delivered by Blender.  If some mesh is slow to display on screen you can show something simpler in its place, such a [display bounding box] or turn on the modifier only at render time, by click on the appropriate button on the modifier.  As an example Subdivision can have a lower setting.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I will do it tomorrow but it happens for sure only on very big meshes but I still think something is off. And that one of the component is clearly to weak

Comment: For some renders you can also indicate to Blender to use the GPU.  Clearly your machine may be powerful,  but any machine has a limit.  Immoderators may enjoy closing your question because they may claim it is subjective.  Listing numbers may help by adding some objective measurement.  You might also consider rendering the ivy as an images and use it as a backdrop image in places of the 3D mesh.

Comment: Good Luck on any of the above techniques.  Mentioning hardware may also get your question closed if certain entities happen to read it.  Toss of the dice.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I render for sure with my gpu. like I stated rendering is fast. but the modifier take a lot of time. like the viewport shading switching if it changed it renders very fast.

Comment: You may reduce or turn off certain modifiers for design and turn on for render time.  Please state which modifiers you believe to consume the most time. Face, Vertex, Edge counts?  You may want to put some subdivision surfaces last in the stack.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I updated the question, to include some stats. more will follow tomorrow

Comment: 16 million faces are extremely overkill. Most average workstations (good) crash on 3-7 million faces

Comment: Ya why in god's name does a face need 16 million vertices, are you modeling each pore in SubD? Decimate that thing to like 1 million and then bake it down before you render it. That's 101 stuff for any 3D package.

Comment: @Jakemoyo actually yes it is for hyper realistic render and every pore is sculpted. so i need a lot of faces

Comment: @Alex use texturing and normal maps for that level of micro detail. Even the VFX and 3D animation in AAA movies likely don't require that level of detail - especially if the camera isn't zooming in to microscopic level (and if it is, you'd employ other tricks). Better to have 8K textures and maps on a lower-poly mesh than vice versa.

Comment: @Onyx im doing things like this https://youtu.be/HlHoIGE2Ocs?t=694.

Comment: @Onyx i heard often about this workflow, that is need for the kind of realism what I want to do. But i also realised I subdived my charackter which is unnecessary. But besides that I have the issue also with smaller meshes

Comment: Zbrush is a fundamentally different software than Blender. It is specifically optimized to handle massive amounts of polygons for hi-res sculpting. There are ways to approximate this with other methods. You either have to tailor your workflow to suit your needs or go use the software that's designed to do that. It's almost as if you were posting about Zbrush not having fine enough control over animation curves or light bounces in a render engine, you're trying to make it do something that other apps are better suited for.

Comment: Have you tried painting the pore detail into the normal map directly? I know alot of character artists will only sculpt in the bigger picture wrinkles that define the features of the face and then just manually paint in the pore detail on the low-poly without worrying about trying to get that detail in the hi-poly. Something like [this workflow](https://ubm-twvideo01.s3.amazonaws.com/o1/vault/gdc2017/Presentations/Adelle_Achieving%20High-Quality.pdf)

Comment: @Jakemoyo thanks for the workflow! i will read it soon. it looked promising. I think the comment thread drifted away from the issue and intention of my question. the problem is also with lower res models. but i think its my ram

Comment: because I see alot of activity on my ssd when the issues occure which mean windows ist using swap which implies that it decide that the ram shouldnt be loaded more

Comment: Probably does have to do with RAM, but you have to ask whether the ways in which you're utilizing RAM are even optimal to begin with. Like if you were in a mechanic shop asking the mechanic to fix a blown head gasket, and it turns out the gasket blew because you were using your '06 Honda to tow a 4,000lb trailer through the Rocky Mountains. The problem is less to do with the blown head gasket and more to do with tempering your expectations and learning to optimize.

Comment: Also known as [The X Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)